# Angular - Sidebar submenu dropdown redirects to Login Page

Tags: angular, adminlte

In my Angular-13 project, I am using AdminLte3. I created Sidebar Sub-Menu. Before I added routerlink, everything was working perfectly.

component:

```
export class AdminSidebarComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor() {
   }

   ngOnInit(): void { 
  }
}
```

html:

```
<li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-close">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-users"></i>
    <p>
      HRM
      <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
    </p>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/employee-list']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
        <p>
          Employees List
        </p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/department-list']" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <p>
          Department List
        </p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

After the user successfully logs in, then he clicks on sidebar dropdown menu, it is expected that it drops down and displays the sub-menu.
Instead of the sub-menu to dropdown, it redirects back to the login page. But when I click on the click to go back on the browser and clicks on the sub-menu again, it drops down.

What could be wrong, and how do I correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the `href` you added to the anchor tag

Comment: I removed the href, but still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Please add those `routerLink` to the `li` items instead of adding them on `a` tag.

And one more thing which needs to be checked is path of the routing which we are providing into the `routerLink`.
As we are adding `/` so it will take relative path.

If it is not relative in your application then please remove that `/` and try then.

I hope it will work.

Please feel free to comment below in case issue still persists.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem starts from here:  <a href="#" class="nav-link active">   I click on this before the sub-menu gets displayed. I think the problem is coming from there.  So, how do I treat this:  <a href="#" class="nav-link active">  in Angular?

Comment: It should not be a problem if you have already removed that href attribute completely